# update query (work items) (intelli j 2018) from TFS 2015

Tags: intellij-idea, tfs

I'm trying to update my query from tfs 2015 to intellij (2018) it hast updated
In intellij the query refers to assigned to me(picture below) same for tfs

Intellij query:
[image: Intellij query]

But in TFS in i made a query and it had a result (see picture below) (via open in browser link)

TFS query:
[image: TFS QUERY]

Comment: Please include all the material in the question itself, rather than using screenshots. The question should be answerable without having to leave StackOverflow.

Comment: Do you mean include the tfs link and .idea file ??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to refresh the work items as the screenshot below shows, or exist your project and re-open it:

[image]

I've tested in ideaIC-2018.2 with `Visual Studio Team Service` plugin, the work items can show without any issue.

Comment: thanks it works  i don't know it was very slow ,  i clicked on the refresh button ,nothing appeared but anyway it works